# mongoid update all documents with conditions

Tags: ruby, mongoid, document

I have a model

```
class Employee
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :first_name
  field :last_name
  field :address1
  field :address2
  field :salary
end
```

Now I need to update all Employee's salary to 10000 whose address1 is "Calgary"

Now I tried this query

```
Employee.update_all "salary = 10000", "address1 = 'Calgary'"
```

But this query gave me error as:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `update_all' for Employee:Class
```

Thanks

Comment: Update: I am currently using mongoid v2.0.0 beta19

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You should try to update your MongoID to latest version. Mongoid 2.0 was released sometime back. I guess update_all, destroy_all and delete_all got introduced in one of the rc's.

After upgrade, following should work

```
Employee.where(:address1 => 'Calgary').update_all(:salary => 10000)
```

Comment: AFAIK the gotcha is that `update_all` is a method on a ResourceList (array of results) and not on the model itself. So you can not call Foo.update_all, but you can call Foo.some_selection.update_all.

Comment: @berkes: you can get "empty" selection by using `Foo.scoped.update_all`

Answer (score 0):

According to this http://groups.google.com/group/mongoid/browse_thread/thread/ac08564d5a38da13?pli=1

and a quick Model.respond_to?(:update_all) outputs true, suggests that Model.update_all is fine

Answer (score 0):

A more up to date way to do it using [`Moped`](https://github.com/mongoid/moped) (the underlying driver):

```
Employee.collection.find(address1: 'Calgary').update_all(salary: 10000)
```

*Weird query BTW :P*